# VSCode Angular & typings: no intellisense

Tags: angularjs, typescript, intellisense, visual-studio-code

I try to set up a new project with angular 1.5.5 and I want to make use of typescript for my code. I use Visual Studio Code as my coding tool.
I added the typings for angular to my project:

```
typings install angular --save --ambient
```

I added a typings.d.ts file and a tsconfig.json file but I don't have intellisense any of the .ts files I've added...
Don't know what am I doing wrong? Can someone help me?
I try setup small project to reproduce the problem: [download link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=F3D1BCA415A23A8D!184&authkey=!ALBAauR94dT3_Rc&ithint=file%2Czip)

Great thx in advance!
Alexander.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your file structure is wrong:

1. `tsconfig.json` should be on the root directory of you app, i.e. `AngularApp`.
2. usually, `typings.d.ts` is there as well.

After you move these two files, remember to change the path inside them. Ts files must be included.

```
//tsconfig.json
{
//...
  "files":[  
    "typings.d.ts",
    "public/app/app.ts"
  ]
}

//typings.d.ts
/// <reference path="typings/browser.d.ts" />
```

[If you want to download.](http://www.filedropper.com/app2_1)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you must have seen an error when executing:

```
typings install angular --save --ambient
```

First of all you must install the new [TypeScript Definition Manager](https://github.com/typings/typings):

```
npm install typings --global
```

then you must use this command in your project's folder:

```
typings install dt~angular --global --save
```

as explained in the [quick start](https://github.com/typings/typings#quick-start).

This command should create a file `typings.json` which should look something like this:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "angular": "registry:dt/angular#1.5.0+20160517064839"
  }
}
```

If you're wondering what that `dt` prefix is, you can run:

```
typings search --name angular
```

and you will see that `dt` represents the source:

[image]

*I think you must restart **VS Code** to see the effects and have intellisense.*

Answer (score 1):

I ran into some issues myself and here are the steps I took to make it work.

- Open the terminal and run...
- `npm install typings -g`
- `cd ~/root of your project`
- I had an error running `typings install dt~angular --save --global`
- I install locally `typings install dt~angular --save`

Notice the typings folder in the root of your project. If you can't see the typings folder restart VS Code or `cmd+shift+p` and type reload and choose `Reload Window`.

In the root also is a `typings.json` file with the following object.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "registry:dt/angular#1.6.0+20170223151516"
  }
}
```

In the root of your project create an **empty** `jsconfig.json`

After creating the `jsconfig.json` file I `Reload Window` again. I opened the `app.js` file and got intellisense for angularjs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to get intellisense is to add a `///<reference path="../typings.d.ts" />` to the top of your typescript files. As you add definitions, make sure to add them to the `typings.d.ts` file.